# Zurb-foundation Section collapses

Tags: zurb-foundation

I am using `zurb-foundation` version 4.1.6 in my rails project.

I have created this page skeleton (excerpt in haml):

```
%body
  .row-fluid
    %nav.top-bar
      %ul.title-area
        %li.name
          %h1= link_to t('app.name'), root_path
        %li.toggle-topbar.menu-icon
          %a{:href => "#"}
            %span Menu
      %section.top-bar-section
        %ul.right
          %li.divider.hide-for-small
          %li.has-dropdown
            = link_to 'Something', '#'
            %ul.dropdown
              %li.has-dropdown= link_to 'Hello', '#'
  .row{:style => "background-color: white; min-height: 800px;margin-top:-30px; padding-top:30px;"}
    .large-12.columns
      .section-container.horizontal-nav{"data-section" => "horizontal-nav", "data-options" => "one_up: false;"}
        %section
          %p.title{"data-section-title" => ""}= link_to 'Section', '#'
          .content{"data-section-content" => ""}
            %ul.side-nav
              %li= link_to 'Link', '#'
              %li= link_to 'Link', '#'
              %li= link_to 'Link', '#'
              %li= link_to 'Link', '#'
              %li.divider
              %li= link_to 'Link', '#'
      / %div.panel
      /   = yield
  = javascript_include_tag "application"
```

Now, the problem is that, the `section` collapses as if it has no content:
[image]

The layout works fine with the static css version of zurb foundation, but has problem with the gem.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved in `zurb-foundation 4.2.1`. Update your gems using `bundle update`.